# How to display JSON list data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am new to Angularjs and having trouble displaying data . i.e. Json array

This is the result of my rest service call:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "Naveen",
        "lastname": "Dutt",
        "email": "navee23ndutt12.vyas@gmail.com",
        "telephone": "7829418456445355"
    }]
}
```

And this is my controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl2', ['$scope', 'NFactory', function ($scope, NFactory) {
    alert("here??");
    $scope.bla = NFactory.query;
    alert("here??" + $scope.bla);

    NFactory.get({}, function (nFactory) {
        $scope.allposts = nFactory.firstname;
    })
}]);
```

This is my html:

```
<div>
    <ul >
        <li ng-repeat="user in bla"> {{ user.firstname }} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

but it doesnt show anything on UI. what can be the problem? please suggest.

Comment: In addition to all the answers, to do some easy debug, I would have printed `{{bla}}`, just to see what the hell was in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you call async task. I would wrap result with promise.

Here is basic simulation of async call:

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1096/)**</kbd>

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, Data) {

        Data.query()
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            $scope.bla = result.users;
        }, function (result) {
            alert("Error: No data returned");
        });


});

app.$inject = ['$scope', 'Data'];

app.factory('Data', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
    var data = {
        "users": [{
            "id": 1,
            "firstname": "Naveen",
            "lastname": "Dutt",
            "email": "navee23ndutt12.vyas@gmail.com",
            "telephone": "7829418456445355"
        }]
    };

//Actually we can use $resource
//var data = $resource('localhost/shfofx/PHP/Rest/alertLossDetails.php', 
//       {},
//      { query: {method:'GET', params:{}}}
//               );
    var factory = {

        query: function (selectedSubject) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();          
            deferred.resolve(data);           
            return deferred.promise;
        }

    }
    return factory;
}]);
```

Comment: This is what rest service returns, and when replaced this above in jsfiddle it doesnt show anything.

Comment: {"users":[{"id":1,"firstname":"Naveen","lastname":"Dutt","email":"naveendutt.vyas@gmail.com","telephone":"7829418355"},{"id":3,"firstname":"sameer","lastname":"sahlot","email":"abc","telephone":"34234324"}]}

Comment: Worked! I creating a list and setting into the object! weird but once i removed it, it worked

Answer (score 1):

If `$scope.bla` in your case is

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"firstname":"Naveen","lastname":"Dutt","email":"navee23ndutt12.vyas@gmail.com","telephone":"7829418456445355"}]
```

then your template should look like this:

```
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="user in bla.users"> {{ user.firstname }} </li>
</ul>
```

Another way would be to change the code inside your `Controller` like this:

```
$scope.bla = NFactory.query.users;
```

and leave template as you have it.

Answer (score 1):

If NFactory.query is string  you need to parse it as JSON first.

```
$scope.bla=JSON.parse(NFactory.query);
```

and then

```
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="user in bla.users"> {{ user.firstname }} </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be a method call: `NFactory.query()` ?

Please show the NFactory source.

UPDATE: Try responding just array from server:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Naveen",
    "lastname": "Dutt",
    "email": "navee23ndutt12.vyas@gmail.com",
    "telephone": "7829418456445355"
}]
```

and use `NFactory.query()`

Comment: services.factory('NFactory', function ($resource) {
    alert("here? servces?");
    return $resource('/ngdemo11/web/users', {}, {

        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {},
            isArray: true
        }
    })
});

Comment: Worked! I creating a list and setting into the object! weird but once i removed it, it worked